# PHP ORDER BY not working nested query

Tags: php, mysql, join

So, I've been trying to create a users' activity page for a practice project, that shows all their activity and their friends' activity on a page. I've got this working, but can't order it by date due to the query being nested. The problem is that I have to first get the user's friends', which is in one table then I have to get notifications which mention this user.

What is the best way make the query so that it can be ordered by date. Thanks for any help!

tables  are set up vaguely like so:

A Users

id  ||  Firstname   || Lastname  || username

B Friends

User_id || Friend id

C wallpost:

Wallpost_id  ||  from_user_id  || to_user_id  ||  wallpost  || DateTime
Code as follows:

```
 try {
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);


$DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

} catch(PDOexception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}

try {
$myid = $_SESSION['identification'];


$result = $DBH->prepare("SELECT Friends.*, users.id, users.Firstname,users.Lastname FROM Friends
        JOIN users ON Friends.Friends=users.id

     WHERE Friends.id=:myid");
$result->execute(array(':myid' => $myid));
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$r = $result->fetchAll();

echo "<br><br><br>";
echo "<ul>";



try{
$stmt = $DBH->prepare("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE usering(`user_id` int(10) , `First_Name` varchar(250), `Last_Name` varchar(250), `user_name` varchar(135), `password` varchar(135), `NaCl` varchar(135))");
$stmt->execute();

$stmy = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO usering(`user_id`, `First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `user_name`, `password`, `NaCl`) SELECT * from users");
$stmy->execute();
}catch(PDOexception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}


try {

foreach($r as $row){

$FriendId = $row['Friends'];

$result2 = $DBH->prepare("SELECT wallpost.*, usering.*, users.* FROM wallpost
JOIN usering ON wallpost.from_user_id=usering.user_id
JOIN users ON wallpost.to_user_id=users.id
 WHERE :FriendId in (from_user_id, to_user_id) ORDER BY wallpost_id DESC
                        ");

$result2->execute(array(':FriendId' => $FriendId));
$result2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$r2 = $result2->fetchAll();
    foreach($r2 as $row2){
    $from_user_id = $row2['from_user_id'];
    $fromUsername = $row2['user_name'];
    $from_user_name = $row2['First_Name'] . " " . $row2['Last_Name'];
    $to_user_name = $row2['Firstname'] . " " . $row2['Lastname'];
    $toUsername = $row2['username'];
    $to_user_id = $row2['to_user_id'];
    $wallpost = $row2['wallpost'];

    /*"<div class='miniprofile_right'><img class='microphoto' src='../" . $from_username . "/profile.jpg'><div class='status_text'><a href='../" . $from_username . "/" . $from_user_id . "profile.php'>" . $from_user_firstname . " " . $from_user_lastname . "</a> => ". $firstname . " " . $lastname . ":</br>" . $walldate2 . "<br>" . $wallpost . " - at " . $walltime .  "</div></div><br><br>"*/
    if($from_user_id == $to_user_id){
    echo "<div class='miniprofile_right'><img class='microphoto' src='../members/" . $fromUsername . "/profile.jpg'><div class='status_text'><a href='../members/" . $fromUsername . "/" . $from_user_id . "profile.php'>" . $from_user_name . "</a> posted a status: <br>" . $wallpost . "</div></div></br></br>";
    } else {
    echo "<div class='miniprofile_right'><img class='microphoto' src='../members/" . $fromUsername . "/profile.jpg'><div class='status_text'><a href='../members/" . $fromUsername . "/" . $from_user_id . "profile.php'>" . $from_user_name . "</a> posted on " . "<a href='../members/" . $toUsername . "/" . $to_user_id . "profile.php'>" . $to_user_name . "'s" . "</a> wall: <br> " . $wallpost . "</div></div></br></br>";
    }
    }
    }
}catch(PDOexception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}

echo "</ul>";




} catch(PDOexception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to not just join on the wallpost table and use that in the order by?

Comment: good thought but i don't think it would order it by date as the join would have to be on either from_user_id and to_user_id

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a class/object and feed the entries into it. After all the query's are ran and the relevant data is in your new class, it should be trivial to sort.

So as long as your queries retrieve the proper information, you can sort the data outside of SQL, if the queries get too long

Comment: What? Why? The DBMS is there for that

Comment: Easier, more control. I imagine you could manipulate the data much easier in many more ways then you could just pure SQL.

Comment: I'm not really a fan of OOP normally - what kind of thing you were imagining?

Comment: I had to use drupal recently *shudders*. Client wanted a very specific way to order the pending orders for shipping. There were multiple rules to how it can be sorted, so by creating an object, I  could fill it with every product from each pending order. Each product would have different properties to sort by. The idea is to let the class  sort by a number of factors, and then return the order list in a sorted fashion.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. So i fixed the issue with a HORRIBLE hack (below). I would really love to make this more efficient so I'm leaving the question open for anyone to make any better suggestions. IN the meantime, I'm looking into @Michael Stevens 's post to see if it will work.

```
try{
$stmt = $DBH->prepare("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE usering(`user_id` int(10) , `First_Name` varchar(250), `Last_Name` varchar(250), `user_name` varchar(135), `password` varchar(135), `NaCl` varchar(135))");
$stmt->execute();

$stmy = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO usering(`user_id`, `First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `user_name`, `password`, `NaCl`) SELECT * from users");
$stmy->execute();
}catch(PDOexception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}

try {




$FriendId = $row['Friends'];

$result2 = $DBH->prepare("SELECT wallpost.*, usering.*, users.* FROM wallpost
JOIN usering ON wallpost.from_user_id=usering.user_id
JOIN users ON wallpost.to_user_id=users.id
ORDER BY WallDateTime DESC
    ");

$result2->execute();
$result2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



$r2 = $result2->fetchAll();
    foreach($r2 as $row2){
    $from_user_id = $row2['from_user_id'];
    $fromUsername = $row2['user_name'];
    $from_user_name = $row2['First_Name'] . " " . $row2['Last_Name'];
    $to_user_name = $row2['Firstname'] . " " . $row2['Lastname'];
    $toUsername = $row2['username'];
    $to_user_id = $row2['to_user_id'];
    $wallpost = $row2['wallpost'];
    $DateTime = $row2['WallDateTime'];
    $same = "";
    try {   
$result = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM Friends WHERE Friends.id=:myid");
$result->execute(array(':myid' => $myid));
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$r = $result->fetchAll();
    foreach($r as $row){
    $FriendId = $row['Friends'];

    //echo $FriendId . " " . $from_user_id . " " . $to_user_id . " " . $wallpost . "<br>";
    //echo "Friend Id is: " . $FriendId . "and to user id is " . $to_user_name . $to_user_id . " whilst from user id name is " . $from_user_name . $from_user_id . "<br>";

    if($from_user_id == $to_user_id){
    $string ="<div class='miniprofile_right'><img class='microphoto' src='../members/" . $fromUsername . "/profile.jpg'><div class='status_text'><a href='../members/" . $fromUsername . "/" . $from_user_id . "profile.php'>" . $from_user_name . "</a> posted a status: <br>" . $wallpost . "<br>" . $DateTime .  "</div></div></br></br>";
    if($same != $string){
    echo $string;
    $same = $string;
    }   

    } elseif($from_user_id == $FriendId){



    $string = "<div class='miniprofile_right'><img class='microphoto' src='../members/" . $fromUsername . "/profile.jpg'><div class='status_text'><a href='../members/" . $fromUsername . "/" . $from_user_id . "profile.php'>" . $from_user_name . "</a> posted on " . "<a href='../members/" . $toUsername . "/" . $to_user_id . "profile.php'>" . $to_user_name . "'s" . "</a> wall: <br> " . $wallpost . "<br>" . $DateTime . "</div></div></br></br>";
    if($same != $string){
    echo $string;
    $same = $string;
    }

    } elseif($to_user_id == $FriendId){


    $string = "<div class='miniprofile_right'><img class='microphoto' src='../members/" . $fromUsername . "/profile.jpg'><div class='status_text'><a href='../members/" . $fromUsername . "/" . $from_user_id . "profile.php'>" . $from_user_name . "</a> posted on " . "<a href='../members/" . $toUsername . "/" . $to_user_id . "profile.php'>" . $to_user_name . "'s" . "</a> wall: <br> " . $wallpost . "<br>" . $DateTime .  "</div></div></br></br>";
    if($same != $string){
    echo $string;
    $same = $string;
    }




    } else {
    }

    }

    }catch(PDOexception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```